# Xcode 8 Beta @import unexpected behavior

Tags: objective-c, xcode, module

So I'm just coming back to programming for macOS after a few years hiatus, and have discovered the @import syntax.  I created a sample program to test it out, but it's not working as my googling seems to suggest that it should.

Test project setup:

1. Open Xcode
2. File>New>Project...
3. Select the Cocoa Application template for macOS. Click Next
4. Name the project "ModuleTest", add organization name and organization Identifier. Select Objective-C as the language, check Use Storyboards, make sure "Create Document-Based Application", "Use Core Data", "Include Unit Tests" and "Include UI Tests" are all unchecked. Click Next and choose a save location. Don't create Git repository, and don't add to any project or workspace. Click Create.
5. In the Navigator, click on Main.storyboard.
6. From the Object Library, drag an AVKit Player View object onto the View  of the View Controller Scene in the Storyboard.

Now at this point, we can see the symptom, which is that if you build the project, a window will pop open, but the player is missing from it, and the xcode output window shows a message such as

> 2016-08-16 09:07:46.465 ModuleTest[19778:4097187] Failed to set
>   (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow):
>   *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (AVPlayerView) for key (NSDestination); the class may be defined
>   in source code or a library that is not linked

This error occurs regardless of whether I put an `@import AVKit;` statement into AppDelegate.h, AppDelegate.m, ViewController.h, ViewController.m, or main.m.  However, simply linking the AVKit.framework in the "Link Binary With Libraries" section of the project's Build Phases, solves the issue, no @import needed anywhere.

So what's going on?  I thought @import was supposed to eliminate the need to manually link frameworks?  Am I going through the process incorrectly? Is this happening because I'm using storyboards?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no actual code that references the AVPlayerView. Try adding a single line of code that uses AVPlayerView and you'll notice that the error is gone.